# Export whole image to jpg, not only elements placed on a sheet of paper

Tags: coreldraw

I want to export image from CDR X3 to jpg.

By default, on exported jpg, there will be only those elements, that are placed on sheet-of-paper-like workspace. On my image I am using *Dimmension tool*, so I want it to be real size in CDR, but that means, that my image is far bigger than this paper workspace.

Any way of exporting whole image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Select all objects: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>
2. Group with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
3. Now export